# pytest Celery plugin error - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'finalize'

Tags: python, celery, pytest

I am currently developing a test suite for a flask app.

This app uses celery for background tasks, therefore I had to implement celery testing plugin within pytest referenced in the celery documentation: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/testing.html.

However, when running the tests I get the following error:

```
ERROR tests/functional/test_auth.py::test_request_recover - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'finalize'
```

Traceback is:

```
________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_request_recover ________________________________________________________

request = <SubRequest 'celery_worker' for <Function test_request_recover>>, celery_app = <function celery_app at 0x7fe188cce670>, celery_includes = ()
celery_worker_pool = 'solo', celery_worker_parameters = {}

    @pytest.fixture()
    def celery_worker(request,
                      celery_app,
                      celery_includes,
                      celery_worker_pool,
                      celery_worker_parameters):
        # type: (Any, Celery, Sequence[str], str, Any) -> WorkController
        """Fixture: Start worker in a thread, stop it when the test returns."""
        if not NO_WORKER:
            for module in celery_includes:
                celery_app.loader.import_task_module(module)
>           with worker.start_worker(celery_app,
                                     pool=celery_worker_pool,
                                     **celery_worker_parameters) as w:

../../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/contrib/pytest.py:194: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
../../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py:73: in start_worker
    with _start_worker_thread(app,
/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
../../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py:106: in _start_worker_thread
    setup_app_for_worker(app, loglevel, logfile)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

app = <function celery_app at 0x7fe188cce670>, loglevel = 'error', logfile = None

    def setup_app_for_worker(app, loglevel, logfile):
        # type: (Celery, Union[str, int], str) -> None
        """Setup the app to be used for starting an embedded worker."""
>       app.finalize()
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'finalize'

../../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py:171: AttributeError
```

The fixtures that I am currently using are the following:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def create_flask_app():
    #drop all records in testDatabase before strting new test module
    db = connect(host=os.environ["MONGODB_SETTINGS_TEST"], alias="testConnect")
    for collection in db["testDatabase"].list_collection_names():
        db["testDatabase"].drop_collection(collection)
    db.close()
    
    # Create a test client using the Flask application configured for testing
    flask_app = create_app()
    return flask_app

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_client(create_flask_app):
    """
    Establish a test client for use within each test module
    """
    with create_flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
        with create_flask_app.app_context():
            yield testing_client 

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def celery_app(create_flask_app):
    from app import celery
    from celery.contrib.testing import tasks
    return celery_app
```

And the test function is:

```
def test_request_recover(create_flask_app, test_client, celery_worker):
    """
    GIVEN a request_recover_page  view function
    WHEN a user submits POST to '/users/requestrecoverpass' with dataform
    THEN check that: (1) the site sends a email to the user with the redirect link, or (2)
        a warning in case the user does not exist
    """
    #test with correct email
    data = {
        "email" : "teste_email_register_user@gmail.com",
    }
    response = test_client.post('/users/requestrecoverpass', data=data, follow_redirects=True)

    response_data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response_data
```

The view function being tested (which calls the celery task) is:

```
@auth_blueprint.route("/requestrecoverpass", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def request_recover_page():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("recover_password_request.html", email_sender="jassocxxi@gmail.com")

    elif request.method == "POST":
        user_mail = request.form["email"]
        user_object = User.objects(email=user_mail)

        if user_object:
            user_object = user_object[0]
            password_recover_code = generate_password_hash(user_object.username + user_object.password + str(randrange(0, 100000)))[10:]
            password_recover_code_hash = generate_password_hash(password_recover_code)
            password_recover_date = datetime.date.today()

            #send correct email
            recover_url = url_for("auth.recover_page", user_serial=user_object.id, recover_code=password_recover_code, _external=True)
            email_data = {
                        'subject': render_template("mail_recover_subject.txt"),
                        'to': user_mail,
                        'body': render_template("mail_recover_password.txt", recover_link=recover_url)
                        }

            user_object.password_recover_code = password_recover_code_hash
            user_object.password_recover_date = password_recover_date
            user_object.save()

        else:
            #send incorrect email
            email_data = {
                        'subject': render_template("mail_recover_subject.txt"),
                        'to': user_mail,
                        'body': render_template("mail_recover_password_wrongemail.txt")
                        }
            

        send_async_email.apply_async(args=[email_data], countdown=5)

        return jsonify(True)
```

Does anyone have an idea of why the test setup is failling?

Comment: The issue lies with the `celery_app` fixture, it's returning a reference to itself and usages of it seem to expect a celery app and not a fixture function.

Comment: You're totally right, thanks for pointing that out, stupid mistake